# Parsing Commented html from mobile website

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Trying to parse this html with the simple_html_dom but most of it is commented how do I get around that? ([It's a mobile page](http://www.bungie.net/mobile/GlobalChallenges.aspx)).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include(dirname(__FILE__) .'/inc/simple_html_dom.php');

$page = 'http://www.bungie.net/mobile/GlobalChallenges.aspx';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);

$wExp = $html->find("#wExpSeconds");

$wExp = htmlspecialchars_decode($wExp->attr['title']);
echo $wExp;

?>
```

....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>
    Bungie.net
</title>

</head>
<body>
<!--
<div id="page">

    <span id="wExpSeconds" title="1304935200000"></span>
    <span id="dExpMilliseconds" title="1304676000000"></span>
    <span id="pageClass" class="reach"></span>
    <div id="mainContent">

        <table class="breadcrumb" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td colspan="3"><img id="headerPlaceholder2" alt="" src="/images/mobile/blankNavIcon.gif" /></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/mobile/ReachOnline.aspx" class="ajax">Back</a></td>
                <td class="middle"><h3>Challenges</h3></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>




        <ul class="challengesList">

                    <li class="weekly">
                        <h3>Weekly Challenge</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img id="main_wcr_img_0" title="Alexandria: LASO" src="/images/reachstats/challenges/1.png" alt="Alexandria: LASO" style="border-width:0px;" />
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h4>Alexandria: LASO</h4>
                                    <p>Completion Reward: 16000cR</p>
                                    <p class="description">Complete Alexandria, Legendary, All Skulls On (LASO).</p>
                                    <p class="time">Time Remaining: <span class="wcd"></span></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>   
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="daily">
                        <h3>Daily Challenges</h3>
                        <ul>

                        <li>
                            <img id="main_dcr_img_0" title="One Spartan Army" src="/images/reachstats/challenges/0.png" alt="One Spartan Army" style="border-width:0px;" />
                            <div class="info">
                                <h4>One Spartan Army</h4>
                                <p>Completion Reward: 1875cR</p>
                                <p class="description">Kill 250 enemies in Firefight Matchmaking.</p>
                                <p class="time">Time Remaining: <span class="dcd"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img id="main_dcr_img_1" title="Blast Radius" src="/images/reachstats/challenges/3.png" alt="Blast Radius" style="border-width:0px;" />
                            <div class="info">
                                <h4>Blast Radius</h4>
                                <p>Completion Reward: 1000cR</p>
                                <p class="description">Kill 40 enemies in Firefight Matchmaking with grenades.</p>
                                <p class="time">Time Remaining: <span class="dcd"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img id="main_dcr_img_2" title="Hyper Lethal Vector" src="/images/reachstats/challenges/3.png" alt="Hyper Lethal Vector" style="border-width:0px;" />
                            <div class="info">
                                <h4>Hyper Lethal Vector</h4>
                                <p>Completion Reward: 1125cR</p>
                                <p class="description">Kill 150 enemies with headshots in Firefight Matchmaking.</p>
                                <p class="time">Time Remaining: <span class="dcd"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img id="main_dcr_img_3" title="Be Their Huckleberry" src="/images/reachstats/challenges/3.png" alt="Be Their Huckleberry" style="border-width:0px;" />
                            <div class="info">
                                <h4>Be Their Huckleberry</h4>
                                <p>Completion Reward: 1250cR</p>
                                <p class="description">Kill 100 enemies in Firefight Matchmaking with the pistol.</p>
                                <p class="time">Time Remaining: <span class="dcd"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                        </ul> 
                    </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

        <p>&copy; 2011 Bungie, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
        <p class="footer_links">
            <a id="mLink" href="/mobile/dl/globalchallenges.aspx">mobile</a>
            <a id="fsLink" href="/mobile/redirect.aspx?path=%2fstats%2freach%2fglobalchallenges.aspx">full site</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $page = 'http://www.bungie.net/mobile/GlobalChallenges.aspx';

    // read page into a string
    $page_str = file_get_contents($page);

    // remove HTML comment tags
    $page_str = str_replace(array('<!--', '-->'), '', $page_str);

    // create SimpleHTMLDom object with the string
    $html = str_get_html($page_str);

    $wExp = $html->find("#wExpSeconds", 0); // only look for the first occurrence
    $wExp = htmlspecialchars_decode($wExp->attr['title']);

    echo $wExp;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
1304935200000
```